# Custom input pattern in textbox with ranging values separated by dots

Tags: regex, validation

I am looking for a code that will validate custom values into the textbox for a window form such that the input entered follows a certain pattern as shown-

```
|"DB1.DBX1.0"|"DB1000.DBB1000.0"|"DB18.DBD4.0"|"DB99.DBW999.0"|
```

such that `DB[1-1000].DB[X,B,D,W][1-1000.0-10]` and if the values match the required pattern the valued would be accepted or else it will show an error.

I have also attached textbox image for the reference.

The textbox looks like such:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try that :

```
DB(1000|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,2})\.DB[XBDW](1000|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,2})\.(0|10|[1-9])
```

Explanation:

1. `DB` matches DB at the start
2. `(1000|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,2})` matches 1000 or 01-09 or [1-9] followed by 0 or 1 or two digits
3. `\.` matches dot
4. `DB` matches DB
5. `[XBDW]` matches any X or B or D or W
6. `(1000|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,2})` matches 1000 or 01-09 or [1-9] followed by or or 1 or two digits
7. `\.` matches dot
8. `(0|10|[1-9])` matches zero or ten or anything between 1 and 9

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c50fT1/4)

Update to your comment:

`DB(\d{1,4}|[1-5]\d{5}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])\.DB[XBDW](1000|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,2})\.(0|10|[1-9])`

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/c50fT1/7)

Comment: This is matching `DB00.DBX00`

Comment: I tried but it wasn't matching , the thing is your pattern wasn't complete... i have understood your context though your sample wasn't a full text... thanks

Comment: Only OP can say. Just another remark, the last part can be reduce to `10|\d`, and I don't know if `DB01` is allowed or `DB001`, I'd say `DB(1000|[1-9]\d{0,2})`. I'll give you +1 if OP accepts your answer.

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman how do i match a number that is upto 65535. Incase of value uptil 1000 i have understood that 1001 wouldn't be accepted in your expression which is :(1000|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,2})
***Kindly give me an expression for DB[X][1-65535]***

Comment: Although this was not your original question, yet I have uodated my answer... Plz accept the ans if that served your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this one please. It works in java.

```
DB((\d{1,3})|(1000))\.DB(X|B|D|W)((\d{1,3})|(1000))\.((\d{1})|(10))
```

Comment: `{1}` is superfluous in `\d{1}`

Comment: This is matching `DB000.DBX000` and it shouldn't.

Comment: @Arman so according to this expression if i enter DB1000.DBX1000.10 it will show me a valid input but it isn't showing me valid input :(

Comment: @arman This worked for me made some changes DB[0-1000]\d{0,3}\.DB[XBDW][0-1000]\d{0,3}\.\d{0,2}$.
Anyways thnx for your help mate :)